# How to summarize statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.3

In order to get final results I need to write lots of queries:

```
SELECT min(x) from table WHERE column1='ab' AND column2='3';
SELECT min(y) from table WHERE column1='ab' AND column2='3';
SELECT max(x) from table WHERE column1='ab' AND column2='3';
SELECT max(y) from table WHERE column1='ab' AND column2='3';
SELECT min(x) from table WHERE column1='ab' AND column2='4';
SELECT min(y) from table WHERE column1='ab' AND column2='4';
SELECT max(x) from table WHERE column1='ab' AND column2='4';
SELECT max(y) from table WHERE column1='ab' AND column2='4';
...
```

where `column2` goes from `3-8`.

I guess I can `CASE` that somehow, and maybe do some sort of `FOR` loop for `column2`, but I have no success with it. Or I can do something else with it?

Wanted result:

```
column2 |  minx  |   miny |   maxx |   maxy |
      3 | number | number | number | number |
      4 | number | number | number | number |
      5 | number | number | number | number |
      6 | number | number | number | number |
      7 | number | number | number | number |
      8 | number | number | number | number |
```

Any help appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you'd use a case in that but seems like a simple use for a group by statement.

```
SELECT Column2, Min(x), Min(y), Max(x), Max(y)
FROM table 
WHERE Column1='ab' AND Column2 > 2 AND Column2 < 9 GROUP BY Column2
```

I normally do T-SQL for MS-SQL but this is pretty basic so I expect this will work on Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Why case? You can just group by column2.

```
select
    column2,
    min(x) as minx,
    min(y) as miny,
    max(x) as maxx,
    max(y) as maxy
from table
where column1 = 'ab' and column2 between 3 and 8
group by
    column2
```